# Differential equation with forces

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a lot of trouble with this problem. I know I have to set up a 2nd order differential equation that sums all the forces acting on the spring (gravity, force of the spring), but I'm not sure how to write it out.

[image: problem]

Thank you.

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1453934/265466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we find the value of $k.$ Let $a$ be the displacement from the original equilibrium point to the new equilibrium point. Then, using Newton's Second Law, we find that, at the new equilibrium point, $ka=mg,$ making 
$$k=\frac{mg}{3}. $$
Then, analyzing the new situation, gravity is essentially removed from consideration. We have that $m\ddot{s}=-ks=-mgs/3,$ or $\ddot{s}=-gs/3.$ The solution is
$$s(t)=-4 \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{g}
    t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=-4 \cos \left(18.074\,t\right). $$

Comment: How would I find k? @adriankeister

Comment: You can balance the force of gravity against the spring force at equilibrium. That is, $ks=mg$ there, so that $k=(2\,\text{kg})(980\,\text{cm/s}^2)/(3\,\text{cm})=653.33\,\text{kg/s}^2.$

Comment: It says that the equation is incorrect, I can't seem to identify where it is incorrect though. @adriankeister

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake. Gravity only plays a role in changing the equilibrium point; then it disappears.

Comment: Yes this equation is correct, but it should be 4cos() instead of -4cos(), thank you! @adriankeister

Comment: The negative is correct if you define $y$ positive up, and the spring is initially pulled down; that is, if the initial pull direction is opposite the positive direction.